# Mysql setup for multiple users with large number of individual options

Tags: mysql, database-design

i'm building a study tool and i'm not sure of the best way to go about structuring my database.

Basically, i have a simple but big table with around 50000 bits of information in it.

info (50'000 rows)

id
info_text

user

id
name
email
password
etc

What i want is for the students to be able to marked each item as studied or to be studied(basically on and off), so that they can tick off each item when they have revised it.

I want to build tool to cope with thousands of users and was wondering what the most efficient/easiest option way of setting up the database and associated queries.

At the moment i would lean towards just having one huge table with two primary keys one with user id and then id of the info they had studied and then doing some sort of JOIN statement so i could only pull back the items that they had left to study.

user_info

user_id
info_id

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have groups of items that will be shared by multiple users, or will the items studied be so varied between the users as to there is no purpose in grouping them together?

Comment: Hey Branko, thanks for replying. I'm not sure that i follow you but basically it's a simple list of sentences for each student to study, ordered by importance. The list is fixed and will not differ from user to user. THe only relationship needed is for the each item(or which there are 50,000) to be studied or not studied on an individual per student basis.

Comment: So, all students always study all items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to model this situation:

[image]

The table in the middle has a composite primary key on USER_ID and ITEM_ID, so a **combination** of the two must be unique, even though individually they don't have to be.

- A user (with given USER_ID) has studied a particular item (with given ITEM_ID) only if there is a corresponding row in the STUDIED table (with these same USER_ID and ITEM_ID values).
- Conversely, the user has not studied the item, if and only if the corresponding row in STUDIED is missing. To pull all items a given user hasn't studied, you can do something like this:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM ITEM
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM STUDIED
      WHERE
          USER_ID = <given_user_id>
          AND ITEM.ITEM_ID = STUDIED.ITEM_ID
  )
  ```

  Or, alternatively:

  ```
  SELECT ITEM.*
  FROM ITEM LEFT JOIN STUDIED ON ITEM.ITEM_ID = STUDIED.ITEM_ID
  WHERE USER_ID = <given_user_id> AND STUDIED.ITEM_ID IS NULL
  ```

The good thing about this design is that you don't need to care about STUDIED table in advance. When adding a new user or item, just leave the STUDIED alone - you'll gradually fill it later as users progress with their studies.

Comment: hi Branko, thanks for the great answer. That's the sort of solution i was thinking of. My concern was that the size of the studied table would become very big, very quickly. Will this effect performance massively or can MYSQL handle that ok.

Comment: @everythingbeforethebutis... Yes it will become big, but databases are built for _efficiently_ handling huge amounts of data. Remember, there is no magic. Each piece of information needs to be physically stored _somehow_ and this is pretty much the most compact _relational_ way of doing it. The indexes should ensure good performance, even on billions of rows. There are non-relational hacks that _might_ save you some space, but will compromise data integrity and probably performance as well, so I strongly recommend against them.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

1) A users table with a uid primary key

2) A enrolled table (this table shows all courses that have enrolled students) with a primary key of (uid, cid)

3) A items (info) table holding all items to study, with a primary key of itemid

Then in the enrolled table just have one attribute (a binary flag) 1 means it has been studyed and 0 means they still need to study it.

Comment: but its not just one course(one on and off). I need it so they have a binary flag for each one of the 50000 pieces of info. Thanks for your time